# How to set date range in Bid Landscapes - Adwords API

Tags: php, google-api, google-ads-api, google-api-php-client, google-api-client

I am playing with [Bid Landscapes](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/bid-landscapes), and as the official documentation describes:

> Bid landscapes are a way for you to research information about estimated performance for your ad groups and criteria.

I am testing the API in AdGroup level, and the following piece of code has been written:

```
public function test_bid_simulator() {
    $user = new AdWordsUser();
    $user->SetClientCustomerId('*******');
    $dataService = $user->GetService('DataService', 'v201509');

    $selector = new Selector();
    $selector->fields = array('AdGroupId', 'StartDate', 'EndDate',
        'Bid', 'LocalClicks', 'LocalCost', 'LocalImpressions');

    // Create predicates.
    $selector->predicates[] = new Predicate('CampaignId', 'IN', array('****', '****', '****', '****'));

    // $selector->dateRange = new DateRange();
    // $selector->dateRange->min = date('Ymd', strtotime('2016/01/28'));
    // $selector->dateRange->max = date('Ymd', strtotime('2016/02/03'));

    do {
        // Make the getAdGroupBidLandscape request.
        $page = $dataService->getAdGroupBidLandscape($selector);

        // Display results.
        if (isset($page->entries)) {
            foreach ($page->entries as $bidLandscape) {
                printf("Found adgroup bid landscape with id '%s' for start "
                        . "date '%s', end date '%s', and landscape points:\n",
                        $bidLandscape->adGroupId,
                        $bidLandscape->startDate,
                        $bidLandscape->endDate);
                foreach ($bidLandscape->landscapePoints as $bidLandscapePoint) {
                    printf("  bid: %.0f => clicks: %d, cost: %.0f, impressions: %d\n", 
                            $bidLandscapePoint->bid->microAmount, 
                            $bidLandscapePoint->clicks, 
                            $bidLandscapePoint->cost->microAmount, 
                            $bidLandscapePoint->impressions);
                }
                print "\n";
            }
        }
        // Advance the paging index.
        $selector->paging->startIndex += AdWordsConstants::RECOMMENDED_PAGE_SIZE;
    } while (isset($page->entries) && count($page->entries) > 0);

    if ($selector->paging->startIndex === 0) {
        print "No adgroup bid landscapes were found.\n";
    }
}
```

This code works fine, and the output is similar to:

```
Found adgroup bid landscape with id '****' for start date   '20160131', end date '20160206', and landscape points:
  bid: 60000 => clicks: 0, cost: 0, impressions: 38
  bid: 110000 => clicks: 0, cost: 0, impressions: 70
  bid: 150000 => clicks: 0, cost: 0, impressions: 97
  bid: 210000 => clicks: 0, cost: 0, impressions: 116
  bid: 280000 => clicks: 0, cost: 0, impressions: 126
  bid: 470000 => clicks: 0, cost: 0, impressions: 136

Found adgroup bid landscape with id '****' for start date '20160131', end date '20160206', and landscape points:
  bid: 20000 => clicks: 0, cost: 0, impressions: 16
  bid: 40000 => clicks: 0, cost: 0, impressions: 89
  bid: 60000 => clicks: 0, cost: 0, impressions: 138
  bid: 100000 => clicks: 0, cost: 0, impressions: 183
  bid: 160000 => clicks: 0, cost: 0, impressions: 218
  bid: 240000 => clicks: 0, cost: 0, impressions: 234
  bid: 390000 => clicks: 0, cost: 0, impressions: 256

etc.
```

By default, the API always picks up the previous week range ending two days from now. For instance, if today is 2016/02/08, the API will get the range between 2016/01/31 and 2016/02/06. My problem is how to set the specific date range in the code. I have commented out this part

```
// $selector->dateRange = new DateRange();
// $selector->dateRange->min = date('Ymd', strtotime('2016/01/01'));
// $selector->dateRange->max = date('Ymd', strtotime('2016/01/31'));
```

because it doesn't work. If I uncomment this part, the code won't give me any results. Any knowledge of how to set a date range for the bid landscapes in Adwords API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have posted exactly the same question in [Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/adwords-api/0EfkcsNf7DU/hg3fDoRMGAAJ). This is how the Google AdWords API Team responded:

> You cannot set date range for BidLandScape. The system does the calculation based on the latest data, generally last 7 days, depending on data availability. BidLandscape is similiar to the Bid Simulator in UI. You can take a look at this [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/adwords-api/bidLandscape/adwords-api/B0lD__BPD0I/vEoL-EVoINsJ) which discussed about BidLandScape.